# Memory not release while converting html to pdf in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, itext, velocity, html-to-pdf

I'm converting html to Pdf, but during this process memory is increase and after completion this process memory not release.Service hold the memory. I'm using Itext for to convert html to pdf.

Sample code :

> dependency

```
       <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
        <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
      </dependency>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext7-core</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.9</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <!-- iText pdfHTML add-on -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>html2pdf</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

> service

```
    @Override
public String createDocument(DemandQuoteStatus demandQuoteStatus) {
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream target = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DemandQuote demandQuote = demandQuoteService.findByQuoteId(demandQuoteStatus.getQuoteId());
        VelocityEngine ve = new VelocityEngine();
        ve.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.RESOURCE_LOADER, "classpath");
        ve.setProperty("classpath.resource.loader.class", ClasspathResourceLoader.class.getName());
        ve.init();
        Template t = ve.getTemplate("templates/proposal-document.vm");
        VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
        Map<String, String> map = findValue(demandQuoteStatus, demandQuote);
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> t2 : map.entrySet()) {
            context.put(t2.getKey(), t2.getValue());
        }
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        t.merge(context, writer);


        HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(writer.toString(), target);
        byte[] bytes = target.toByteArray();
        InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        Users users = userService.findByUserId(demandQuote.getQuotes().getUserId());
        String url = amazonS3Service.uploadFiles(inputStream, users.getUserId(), ImageType.PROPOSAL_RAW, demandQuoteStatus.getQuoteId() + ".pdf", (long) bytes.length);
        if (Objects.isNull(url)) {
            throw new AppException(ExceptionMessage.FILE_GENERATION_ISSUE, HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED);
        }

        inputStream.close();
        target.close();

        return url;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new AppException(ExceptionMessage.FILE_GENERATION_ISSUE, HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED);
    }
}
```

Comment: I had the same problem as him. Did you solve the problem? Ritesh Srivastav